# Google Analytics - Using Client ID as a custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics

Can I use client ID as a dimension in my reports? Client ID does not appear as a dimension in the Dimensions and Metrics Explorer, but I believe I can create a custom dimension that will store the Client ID. My end goal is to have a row per customer/date+time containing the incidents associated with the particular customer at the particular time, e.g. page visits, particular events etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about creation of custom dimensions in the google analytics website for use with processing it is not programing related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've created the custom dimension in GA, you can start tracking it via analytics.js with the following code:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  // Assumes dimension is at index 1.
  tracker.set('dimension1', tracker.get('clientId'));
});
```

Comment: Philip thank you for your reply.  Could you please guide me where to embed the code?

Comment: Read the guides listed under "Fundamentals" in the analytics.js documentation, and that should help you: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Answer (score 0):

I found that the google analytics will NOT save your custom dimension if it matches the value of "client id" (even if that id isn't actually PII). However, if you alter the "client id" to become a different value, it will save properly.

[Here are the guidelines about what you are allowed to send](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en)