# Google Analytics - How to identify sessions when downloading data through API

Tags: google-analytics

I plan to download data from Google Analytics through API, possibly hits using Client ID as a primary dimension.  However, I do not know how to identify the sessions in which these hits belong.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already set up and [started tracking client ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933020/google-analytics-using-client-id-as-a-custom-dimension/40950291#40950291) as a custom dimension, then you can report on which hits belong to which session via the [`ga:sessionCount`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_sessioncount) dimension.